# Occasional keyboard stutter - only on Linux

Tags: keyboard, 64-bit

My keyboard (built-in to the laptop) occasionally freezes for a second or two, repeating the last input before it hangs, thus:

> This is a sample seeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

It recovers within a couple of seconds, but as my job is typing, this is hardly ideal for me.

Set-up is as below (CPU/GPU for completeness, but I don't think either of those is a problem):

- **Laptop**: PCSpecialist Cosmos IV
- **Motherboard**: Clevo W65
- **CPU**: Intel i5-6300HQ
- **GPU**: GeForce GTX 950M
- **RAM**: 12 GiB DDR3L-1600 (8 + 4 GiB)
- **OS**: Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 x86_64 under UEFI (but also happens under BIOS)
- **Keyboard**: Built-in, can't find details?

It doesn't do it under Windows - I had Windows 10 running on a separate drive on this machine, until last week. It HAS done it under Linux for as long as I've owned the laptop, under Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu Budgie 16.10, and Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.

(It also happens on my Win10 VM running on top of the Ubuntu install. I wouldn't have expected otherwise, but again, here for completeness.)

This does NOT happen when I attach an external Bluetooth or USB keyboard, at all. This also does not seem to happen with the built touchpad (although I don't use it at all, I don't remember it ever doing anything weird when I did use it briefly when setting up the computer), nor with an external USB trackball.

It happens on A/C power and battery power. (I did briefly suspect the A/C power, as we do get fairly frequent flickering lights - our supply isn't the cleanest.)

I've grepped dmesg, and the only entry for the keyboard, that I can see, is this one, with no later unplug-replug events:

```
[    2.035560] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
```

I also couldn't see anything other than the initial set-up when I grepped Xorg.0.log.

```
[    81.139] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    81.140] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 48 paused 0
[    81.140] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    81.141] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    81.141] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    81.141] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4"
[    81.142] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    81.142] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
```